# Validating time is not in the past without triggering error when a second has past after you selected the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this validate on my model:

```
def time_in_future
  if start_at?
    errors[:base] << 'The Start Date can not be in the past.' if start_at < Time.zone.now
  end
end
```

But every time I try to save I get the error that I'm asking for in my validation, which makes sense. I assume because Time is down to the second no matter when I save, the time that automatically loads on my datetimepicker is going to be a time in the past because it takes more than a second to select the time then click "Save".

I've thought of a couple solutions, the simplest of which would be to have the error message read `"The Start Date must be a time in the Future."` Easy enough. Or, before saving, the start_at time will automatically be saved some time in the future, I was thinking 15 minutes.

I assume this must be a situation that people regularly encounter, Is there a better or more common way to solve this situation?

I appreciate your input.

Edit:

My updated method after taking input:

```
def time_in_future
  if start_at? do
      errors[:base] << 'The Start Date must be in the future. Seconds count!' if start_at < DateTime.current + 15.minutes
  end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the method "start_at?" ? It checks "start_at?" first and down there it check for a "start_at" (attribute, I assume)

Comment: I just had a huge `Time` headache, and what I learned is to absolutely use `DateTime.current` anytime you can.  It has the timezone present.  You could probably just do `(start_at + 1.minute) < DateTime.current`

Comment: @RonanLopes start_at? just checks for the presence of a date before it checks to see if the date is in the future. I'm still pretty new at developing, is there a better way to write this?

Comment: @JoeEssey I'm using .now is there a distinction between .now and .current?

Comment: `.current()` returns `Time.zone.now` if timezone is set.  I find more readable since nobody working the code has to keep in mind if timezone is in play or not.  It just is.  http://apidock.com/rails/Time/current/class

Comment: @Lenocam yes, there is... but first, what is the data type of start_at attribute?

Comment: @RonanLopes DateTime

Answer (score 1):

Another possible suggestion, which I've actually implemented on large-scale production sites is to have a "grace period." For us, this grace period was 2 hours, but could be as short as a few seconds - it depends on your exact need.

So, my code looked something like:

```
def time_in_future
  if start_at?
    errors[:base] << 'The Start Date can not be in the past.' if start_at < Time.current + 2.hours
  end
end
```

The benefit of this model is that the `2.hours` could be set per environment, which would make testing and troubleshooting other aspects of your model which involve `start_at` much easier.